# Can't stop DatePicker moving due to soft keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, resize, datepicker, soft-keyboard

I have a DatePicker and upon entering my activity the soft keyboard appears. When it opens, it shifts everything upwards, which causes a button and the calender to overlap. I've looked around and tried a few things, such as aligning the datepicker to bottom and adding the following to AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

but it doesn't seem to work. This is really getting on my nerves now and I'd appreciate help.

Current xml for activity:

```
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/title" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/editme"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="saveHW"
        android:text="@string/save" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` for the picker in the xml file.